# Regex java with a specific start and then anything but some characters

Tags: java, regex, string

I've been struggling with Java Regex
I want my regex to with 2 specific characters and then anything that matches the second group

```
String regex = "(^[a-zA-Z | _])([a-zA-Z0-9\\-_^\\s]*)";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);

String s1 = "hello world";
String s2 = "_Sau90-jds";
String s3 = "5_idsjd";
String s4 = "A-next";

ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(s1);
list.add(s2);
list.add(s3);
list.add(s4);

for (String string : list) {
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
    }
}
```

The result I want :

```
_Sau90-jds
A-suivant
```

But I keep having

```
hello world
_Sau90-jds
A-suivant
```

My string has to start with a letter a-zA-Z or "_" and then it can ONLY contain letters, digits, underscores and hyphens, which means no White spaces.

I tried `String regex = "(^[a-zA-Z | _])([a-zA-Z0-9\\-_\\S]*)"`

And `String regex = "(^[a-zA-Z | _])([a-zA-Z0-9\\-_]*)"`

but both of them gave me

```
hello
_Sau90-jds
A-next
```

Comment: See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/rKMkn5) based on ctwheels' idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Brief

There are a few things in your regex that cause it to not work as you expect.

- `[a-zA-Z | _]` says to match any character present in the set, thus, this matches `a-zA-Z |_` (literally). So you're actually including a match on the `|` character, as well as the space  character.
- `[a-zA-Z0-9\-_^\s]*` says to match any character present in the set, thus, this matches `a-zA-Z0-9-_^\s` (literally). So you're actually including a match on the `^` character, as well as any whitespace character.
- Also, not adding the `$` (end of line assertion), you're going to match `hello`, which you've seen in your results.

---

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/9cfaUI/2)

```
^[^\W\d][\w-]*$
```

It's basically the same as

```
^[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*$
```

---

### Results

#### Input

```
hello world
_Sau90-jds
5_idsjd
A-next
```

#### Output

```
_Sau90-jds
A-next
```

---

### Explanation

- `^` Assert position at the start of the line
- `[^\W\d]` Match any word character except digits
- `[\w-]*` Match any word character or hyphen `-` any number of times
- `$` Assert position at the end of the line

Comment: Thanks for your answer, both work fine. 
What did i do wrong ? the groups ? of the missing "$"

Comment: @GeekJunior I've added an explanation in the **Brief** section in my answer that explains why your regex isn't working as you'd expect.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take your requirements:

> My string has to **start with a letter a-zA-Z or "_"** and **then it can ONLY contain letters, digits, underscores and hyphens**, which means no White spaces.

and construct the regex step by step.

1. > start with a letter a-zA-Z or "_"

   ```
   ^[a-zA-Z_]
   ```
2. > then it can ONLY contain letters, digits, underscores and hyphens

   ```
   [a-zA-Z\d_-]+
   ```

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It should be matched according to OP's requirements. Which is why I highlighted the parts in my answer.

Comment: @MarounMaroun Thanks for your answer, i should have been more clear when i wrote my last result.
Anyway, hello shouldn't be part of the result.

Answer (score 0):

```
Please try this :

public class Regex {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String regex = "^[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*$";
        String regexPhase2 = "(^[a-z])([a-zA-Z0-9\\-_^\\s]*)";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);

        String s1 = "hello world";
        String s2 = "_Sau90-jds";
        String s3 = "5_idsjd";
        String s4 = "A-next";

        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(s1);
        list.add(s2);
        list.add(s3);
        list.add(s4);

        for (String string : list) {
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
            if (matcher.find()) {
               System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
            }
        }
    }
}
```